# Django crispy forms field type date

Tags: django-crispy-forms

I am trying to get date picker functionality like HTML `<input type="date">` in django crispy form layout field below.

```
Field('invoice_date', type='date'),
```

However, its not working. Full snippet below:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InvoiceForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_tag = True
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-md-3 create-label'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-md-9'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Div(
                Field('customer'),
                Field('invoice_num'),
                Field('invoice_date', type='date'),
                Fieldset('Add detail', Formset('details')),
                HTML("<br>"),
                ButtonHolder(Submit('submit', 'save')),
                )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed this by making simple widget for a form field.

1. You have to set input type "date" and provide possible default date value in ISO format:

widgets.py

```
from django.forms import DateInput
class DatePicker(DateInput):

    input_type = "date"
    
    def format_value(self, value):
        return value.isoformat() if value is not None and hasattr(value, "isoformat") else ""
```

2. In your forms.py change widget for field 'invoice_date' to DatePicker and you will enable picker functionality:

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .widgets.py import DatePicker
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    invoice_date = forms.DateField(widget=DatePicker())
    ...
```